# PHP detect if the entered timestamp range is greater than one day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a datepicker form that selects a date between two ranges.  When the submit button is pressed it calls a query to grab the data between those two dates.  What I want to do is if they select a a date range that is greater than 24 hours, it will only display the totals of each day instead of every single data in a single day for everyday that they chose.  The form I have right now has it timestamp format yyyy-dd-mm hh-mm-ss. How do I detect this using PHP?

Example Table

```
    Date                  Count 
    2016-04-23 06:26:11     75
    2016-04-23 07:30:12     90
    2016-04-24 12:26:11     100
    2016-04-24 06:27:14     200
    2016-04-25 08:16:19     102
    2016-04-26 13:10:07     300
```

Example Code

```
$link=Connection();

$data1 = '2016-04-23 06:26:11';
$data2 = '2016-04-23 06:30:11';
//if(isset($_POST['range1']) && $_POST['range2']){
//$data1 = $_POST['range1'];
//$data2 = $_POST['range2'];

$dteStart = new DateTime($data1);
$dteEnd = new DateTime($data2);
$dteDiff = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
echo $dteDiff->format('%a'); 

//Display one day of values
if($dteDiff == 0){
    $result = mysql_query(
                      "
                      SELECT DISTINCT Date, Count
                      FROM testLocation 
                      WHERE Date 
                      BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%'
                      "
                      ,$link
                      );        
}
//Sum each day for the month
else if($dteDiff > 0 && $dteDiff < 30){
    $result = mysql_query(
                          "
                          SELECT DISTINCT Date, Count
                          FROM testLocation 
                          WHERE Date 
                          BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%'
                          "
                          ,$link
                          );
}
//Sum each month for the year
else if($dteDiff > 30){
    $result = mysql_query(
                          "
                          SELECT DISTINCT Date, Count
                          FROM testLocation 
                          WHERE Date 
                          BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%'
                          "
                          ,$link
                          );
};
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: thanks, thats helpful

Comment: What do you mean "it will only display the totals of each day "? Also, can you please show us an example of what type of information you have inside the columns `Date` and `Count`

Comment: I added some code and a table example.  basically if someone selects a range that is greater than 24 hours such as between 2016-04-23 12:00:00 and 2016-04-25 12:00:00.  It will sum the total counts for each day and query that instead of getting every single count of each day.

Comment: You can use SUM(Count) in your mysql query.

Comment: True I can sum the count but I only want to sum each day separately because I am generating a graph displaying the total counts for each day

Comment: For that you are already using DISTINCT. Which means distinct date's count will be summed

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Count)
      FROM testLocation 
      WHERE Date 
      BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%' GROUP BY date(Date)
```

OR

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Count)
      FROM testLocation 
      WHERE Date 
      BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Updated

```
SELECT DATE(Date) as dategroup, SUM(Count)
  FROM testLocation 
  WHERE Date 
  BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%' GROUP BY DATE(Date)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but my count just gives a blank value

Comment: Did you try both the mysql queries?

Comment: Yes I did try both

Comment: Instead of DATE_FORMAT try STR_TO_DATE

Comment: That didnt work either, it didnt even load the query.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_date, SUM(Count) FROM testLocation 
      WHERE Date 
      BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%' GROUP BY formatted_date

Comment: What is the data type of column date?

Comment: Have you check what does `SELECT Date FROM testLocation WHERE Date BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%'` does yield

Comment: Yes I have, it will display the column of dates in time stamp form I have entered into the database